# display records from db table for specific user logged in

Tags: php, sql, select, mysqli

I am trying to get records from a db table for a specific user logged in and got a weird issue, Similar code works for getting different data from a different db table so copied and pasted it on a new row and altered the code for the data I want to get from the db table but it's just saying error: could not able to execute

The code is below

```
$sql = "SELECT comm_log_id, DATE_FORMAT(commlogdate, '%d/%m/%Y') AS commlogdate, commlogtime, type, notes, user_name FROM customers_comm_log WHERE user_name='".$_SESSION['user_name']."' ORDER BY comm_log_id desc";
```

In phpmyadmin, I ran the query `SELECT comm_log_id, DATE_FORMAT(commlogdate, '%d/%m/%Y') AS commlogdate, commlogtime, type, notes, user_name FROM customers_comm_log WHERE user_name='ianhaneytestfour' ORDER BY comm_log_id desc` and it outputs the data so wondering if it's to do with the php $_SESSION bit but that works fine for the data displayed on the row above on the php page I have

I can't see where it's going wrong though as it's working on the row above this code with the issue, I have compared the code and is the same apart from the table column names different

Comment: Some basic debugging is needed.. add `var_dump($sql);` on the next line and see if it outputs what you expect. Maybe the session isn't initialised or something.

Comment: What is the actual error you get?

Comment: P.S. "error: could not able to execute" sounds like something you made up (partly because of the bad grammar) and placed somewhere in your code, rather than a real PHP error message. If an error is occuring, you need to log the real error details, not just something meaningless which you invented. You also need to make clear to us which line of code is throwing the error.

Comment: I added `var_dump($sql)` before posting to see what it outputted and it shows the following

string(193) "SELECT comm_log_id, DATE_FORMAT(commlogdate, '%d/%m/%Y') AS commlogdate, commlogtime, type, notes, user_name FROM customers_comm_log WHERE user_name='ianhaneytestfour' ORDER BY comm_log_id desc"

Comment: Ok so that rules that out. So if it's still crashing, you need to find out where and how. That line of PHP/SQL is not directly causing any crash, for sure. See my last comment above about finding the real error message and its location.

Comment: I just checked the error log on the server and that has the following

PHP Warning:  mysqli_close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in user-account.php on line 250

On line 250 is `mysqli_close($link);`

Thinking is that the real issue?

Comment: It's not clear. It could be. Although a warning would not crash it completely, necessarily. You mentioned you see this error "could not able to execute" which presumably comes from some `echo` statement in your code, I would guess. So you need to trace where that comes from, and find out under what conditions it could be shown. That would give you a clue.

Comment: ok will see if can trace it back to where it came from and go from there

Comment: set $username= $_SESSION['user_name'] then use on query like: WHERE user_name=='$username'

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I have sorted the issue and am stupid for not seeing it, I had `mysqli_close($link);` in the code where it was working so I was closing the mysql connection before the latest code I put in so removed that connection line and just left in at the end of the latest code I added in and it's working all ok now, hope that makes sense